# Find Those Chess Notations! #2.5

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Yet again, just another small one that I created before the next big one sometime tomorrow!

Number Of Moves: 7

Checkmater: White

Given Game (Regular Chess Notation):
1. ? ?

2. ? ?
3. ? ?
4. ? O-O
5. ? g5
6. ?+ ?
7. Rxh7#

Cryptic Clue: Jerusalem

Task: To use retrograde analysis and give an answer with all of the question marked moves solved, along with reasons for each move. A simple PGN post shall suffice.

Good luck!

Hint:

> The white queen is not involved in the checkmate at ALL!

Comment: (ROT13) Wrehfnyrz vf va gur Rnfg. Qbrf guvf vzcyl gung gur tnzr vf pbapragengrq nebhaq gur rnfg bs gur purff obneq? V zrna, oynpx pnfgyvat znxrf gur xvat tb gb t8 ba gur rnfg fvqr, evtug orsber purpxzngr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

> 1. a4 e5
>  2. Ra3 Bd6
>  3. Rh3 Ne7
>  4. c3 0-0
>  5. Qb3 g5
>  6. Qxf7+ Kh8
>  7. Rxh7#
>  [PGN Viewer (apronus)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_e5_Ra3_Bd6_Rh3_Ne7_c3_O-O_Qb3_g5_Qxf7*_Kh8_Rxh7M)

Reasoning:

> We need to exclude right rook from attacking because otherwise would waste a move. Which is why I use the left pawn opening to develop left rook to attack the right side. Then use Queen to check on 6th move and use the developed left rook to mate black.

### Update

This time I believe I found the solution based on hint no Queen involved:

> 1. a4 g6
>  2. Ra3 Bg7
>  3. Rh3 Nf6
>  4. Nc3 0-0
>  5. Ne4 g5
>  6. Nxf6+ Kh8
>  7. Rxh7#
>  [PGN Viewer (apronus)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_g6_Ra3_Bg7_Rh3_Nf6_Nc3_O-O_Ne4_g5_Nxf6*_Kh8_Rxh7M)
>  [Variant](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nc3_g6_Ne4_Bg7_a4_Nf6_Ra3_O-O_Rh3_g5_Nxf6*_Kh8_Rxh7M)

Similar reasoning:

> We need to exclude right rook from attacking because otherwise would waste a move. Which is why I use the left pawn opening to develop left rook to attack the right side. Then use Knight to check on 6th move and use the developed left rook to mate black.

Comment: Here’s the cryptic clue explained: Jerusalem is in Israel, a country on the Arabian Peninsula. And this is an Arabian Mate! ;¥

Comment: I thought it was the journey from west to east. Since knight and rook went out of the way from left to right side. Lol

Comment: @RewanDemontay Equating "Israel" and "Arabian" would offend a *lot* of people ;-) However, Jerusalem being in Palestine, which is an Arab country, does make the hint work.